# Power BI Desktop ODBC connection to Firebird

Tags: odbc, firebird, powerbi-datasource

I have trouble to connect my Power BI desktop to ODBC DSN to Firebird database.
My System DSN with Firebird driver is connected successfully from ODBC settings.
When I select my DSN (correct DSN is selected) in Power BI Desktop an error occurs:

> Unexpected error: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is
>   often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

I tested several ways how to fix it (check 64/32bit, versions of driver, Admin permissions) nothing works. Please could anybody help me?

Comment: Which version of the Firebird ODBC driver do you use, which version of fbclient.dll? Is PowerBI desktop 64 bit or 32 bit? What is the configuration of the DSN?

Comment: Hi, it seems there is a trouble in Microsoft side, I received info that it will be fixed in Deecember 2017. See topic in Power BI community:http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/Power-BI-ODBC-to-Firebird-Error/m-p/314850#M36197